# SQL Ordering Results from Other Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
`users`
`id` INT(11)
`name` VARCHAR(30)

`items`
`id` INT(11)
`name` VARCHAR(30)
`owner` VARCHAR(30)
```

And here is my problem: I'm trying to order the `users` table by the number of unique items that they have in the `items` table.

To get unique number of items:

```
SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `owner`='".$ownername."' GROUP BY `name`
```

Running this query gives me the number of unique items for some `$ownername`.

What I'm trying to do is order the `users` table by the number of unique items that they have in the `items` table, and I'm not sure how I would do that.

Comment: `ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT items.ID) DESC`

Comment: Sorry, I just selected all of the suggested tags. It's mySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join, group and sort by count:

```
SELECT u.name
FROM users u
JOIN items i
WHERE u.owner='".$ownername."' 
GROUP BY u.name
ORDER BY COUNT(i.id) DESC
```

Or you can sort by the result of a subselect that counts the items per user:

```
SELECT u.name
FROM users u
WHERE u.owner='".$ownername."' 
ORDER BY
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items i WHERE i.owner = u.name) DESC
```

The latter you could also write slightly differently if you want to show the value too:

```
SELECT u.name,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items i WHERE i.owner = u.name) as item_count
FROM users u
WHERE u.owner='".$ownername."' 
ORDER BY
  item_count DESC
```

Comment: I used the last solution and it worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i used `left join` so that users with no items also show up.

```
select u.name , count(distinct i.name) as NumberOfItems
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN items i
on u.name = i.owner
order by count(distinct i.name) desc
```